# Get Workitems from VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm having some troubles to get all workitems/tasks and who is an assignee.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441955/1420841) is possible get the tasks using the *report work*, but is retrieving absolutely all.

```
https://xxx.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Is possible retrieve the **id**, **title** and **who** is an assignee?

Comment: What problem are you encountering when using that REST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add parameter `fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.AssignedTo` in the api:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.AssignedTo&includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below PowerShell script to call the REST API and retrieve the work item `id`, `title` and `assignee` and any other elements you needed.

Alternatively you can export the work item list to a `*.csv` file.

---

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com",
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "Password/PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2"         
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).values
$wits = $response | where({$_.fields.'System.WorkItemType' -eq 'Task'}) # Only retrieve Tasks

$witrevisions = @()

foreach($wit in $wits){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WitID" = $wit.fields.'System.Id'   
          "rev" = $wit.fields.'System.Rev'
          "Title" = $wit.fields.'System.Title'
          "AssignedTo" = $wit.fields.'System.AssignedTo'
          "ChangedDate" = $wit.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
          "ChangedBy" = $wit.fields.'System.ChangedBy'
          "WorkItemType" = $wit.fields.'System.WorkItemType'
        } 

    $witrevisions += $customObject      
}

$witrevisions | Select-Object `
                WitID,
                rev,
                Title, 
                AssignedTo,
                ChangedDate, 
                ChangedBy,
                WorkItemType #| export-csv -Path D:\temp\WIT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]