# How to get the workitems from AzureDevOps with RestApi in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

```
 Param(
      [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com",
      [string]$project = "projectname",
      [string]$token = "PAT"
       )

        # Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
         $base64AuthInfo = 
         [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}" -f 
         $token)))

         $baseUrl = 
         "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions? 
         includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2"         
           $response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get - 
           UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f 
           $base64AuthInfo)}).values
           $wits = $response | where({$_.fields.'System.WorkItemType' -eq 
           'Task'}) # Only retrieve Tasks

           $witrevisions = @()

           foreach($wit in $wits){

           $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
           "WitID" = $wit.fields.'System.Id'   
           "rev" = $wit.fields.'System.Rev'
           "Title" = $wit.fields.'System.Title'
           "AssignedTo" = $wit.fields.'System.AssignedTo'
           "ChangedDate" = $wit.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
           "ChangedBy" = $wit.fields.'System.ChangedBy'
           "WorkItemType" = $wit.fields.'System.WorkItemType'
             } 

           $witrevisions += $customObject      
             }

           $witrevisions | Select-Object `
                WitID,
                rev,
                Title, 
                AssignedTo,
                ChangedDate, 
                ChangedBy,
                WorkItemType #|export-csv -Path E:\ashwin\devdata.csv - 
                 NoTypeInformation


                 Write-Output $witrevisions
```

I want to display the workitems in my project to be displayed using powershell with the following Rest Api using my PAT.

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1

Comment: What have you tried and what did you observe?

Comment: I followed the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499392/get-workitems-from-vsts , where as i did'nt got any output nor error, I am new to power shell script.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the steps/command you executed and your observations. Referring to another question/answer does very little in this regard.

Comment: I edited the question with what I tried. @A.Kootstra

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the workitems from AzureDevOps with RestApi in Powershell

The result will display in the output, you will find like following:

[image]

If you do not find above output, make sure you have workitem with Task type, because you have set the condition `'System.WorkItemType' -eq 'Task'` in the powershell scripts.

On the other hand, you could export the work item list to a `*.csv` file, this part of the code is commented in powershell:

```
WorkItemType #| export-csv -Path G:\temp\WIT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to create a `*.csv` file, you need to remove the `#` in that line, it should be :

```
WorkItemType | export-csv -Path G:\temp\WIT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Now, we could get that file in our local folder:

[image]

**Note:** The path is `G:\temp` is a local path, you should use the private agent, if you are using the hosted agent, you should copy that file from the hosted agent, and publish it to pipeline artifact.

Hope this helps.