# To check a field in work items before deploying to main or before completing a pull request in Azure DevOps Git repository

Tags: azure-devops, devops, customization, pull-request

We have a requirement from our client that they need a criteria to be met firstly before being able to be merged to ‘main’. Its okay to go in ‘develop’ but when it should go to ‘main’ want to have some sort of TAG, check box, a field or something similar to that on the PBI/BUG which ‘blocks’ the deployment to ‘main’ unless ticked/approved/removed.

Repository: Azure DevOps, Git
Pull request will be from Develop to main branch.

I checked in blogs, but i couldn't find any proper option for this.
Please let me know if we have any options for this.

Answer (score 0):

As an out-of-box solution, no. But you can add a build step (or a separate validation build pipeline) that performs the following through the rest api:

1. Get work items ids of a pull request: [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)
2. Get work items details: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

Check the example: [Get Workitems from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499392/get-workitems-from-vsts)

Additionally, you can use Azure CLI:

1. [az repos pr work-item list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest)
2. [az boards work-item show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#az-boards-work-item-show)

Use this variable to get an active pull request id in your build: [System.PullRequest.PullRequestId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services)